# Error using FFMPEG to create videos from a list of images

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a text file that contains the path of some images(the images are in order in the text file), the file looks like this:

```
/home/Recording-Session-1456734351095_images/output_0001.png
/home/Recording-Session-1456734351095_images/output_0002.png
/home/annotations/rec_1456734351095/annotated_output_0003.png
.......
```

I want to use `ffmpeg` to create a video from these images. Here is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -f image2 -i images.txt -c:v libx264 -r 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

but it gives me this error:

```
[image2 @ 0x32ce7a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none, none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
```

I tried different numbers for `analyzeduration` and `probesize`, but the error still exists, any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The images demuxer does not take a text file as input. You can use the concat demuxer or collect your images in one folder and make them consecutively named.

Using concat demuxer,

```
ffmpeg -r 20 -f concat -i images.txt -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Or using image2

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i /home/Recording-Session-1456734351095_images/output_%04d.png -c:v libx264 -r 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

It's preferable to do the latter.